# Storing ArrayList Elements in a String

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Write a statement that will remove the first element of the ArrayList names and store it in String firstName.

So this problem seems very simple and straight forward, this is answer I came up with:

```
 String firstName = names[0]; 
 names.remove(0);
```

But my teacher said it was wrong and that the answer is:

```
 firstName = names.remove(0);
```

I agree that the second code is correct, but I am still convinced that my code is also correct. Can someone explain to me why it is wrong?

Comment: are you sure the first code is in valid syntax in java?

Comment: In what language you are writing?!!!

Comment: Did you try to run your example?  Or even compile it?  My best guess is that you're using Java, in which case, hint: `ArrayList` != array.

Comment: You can not access any element of ArrayList as names[0] in java.  It should have been names.get(0)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access an element of an `ArrayList` by using `list[0]` -- that syntax is for *Arrays*. The major difference between an *Array* and an `ArrayList` is difference is that an *Array* is a fixed length data structure while `ArrayList` is a variable length Collection class.

[ArrayList Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

---

You can use something like these examples:

Get the first element in the list.

```
String s1 = list.get(0);
```

Get the first element in the list and remove it from the list.

```
String s2 = list.remove(0);
```

Comment: @Javasaurus if your question is solved then don't forget to accept one answer so others know it has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java or android (according to your name), then you cannot access arrayList Items like this:

```
names[0];
```

it should be something like this:

```
names.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the logic, you are right! Storing the first element in a string and then removing it from the list shouldn't be a problem. But I think your teacher wants you to learn more about `java`, here.. emphasizing that `remove` function of `ArrayList` returns the element removed. etc..

If you are talking about syntax, previous answers say it!

HTH!